# Selecting a single row from a column that has multiple rows

Tags: sql, select

I'm a SQL newbie so bear with me.

I am writing a select statement to select data from multiple tables which I have done however when I try to select a specific column I get duplicates as that column can rightly have multiple rows. What I want to do is select the most appropriate row and select that.

My code so far:

```
Select 
    a.[StudentId], a.[Name], a.[StartDT], a.[EndDT], 
    b.[ClassID], b.[Module], b.[ModStart], b.[ModEnd]
from
    [Data].[StudentTbl] a
left join 
    [Data].[ClassTbl] b on a.[StudentId] = b.[Student_ID]
```

When I select the `b.[Module]` I'm getting multiple rows as there can be a number of modules per class however I am wanting to select the `b.[Module]` the student has completed before leaving.

Essentially if the `a.[EndDT]` is equal to `b.[ModEnd]`, I need that specific row. Max function doesn't always work as there are DQ issues within the `ClassTbl` that  when a student has left a row is inserted after the last module saying N/A

What I'm currently getting is this:

[image]

What I want to get eventually:

[image]

Comment: Are you using MS Access?  If so, then please add the "Access" tag to your question.

Comment: Your image is not showing. Can you please write down what you want and what you currently getting.